# IPv6 CPU utilization in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, cpu, ipv6

How can I find out how much CPU is used on my Ubuntu to deal with abrupt IPv6 traffic? I use top command but I can not find out which process ID is dealing with the 11MBps IPv6 inbound into my NIC.

Thank you.

Comment: You assume that 11mbps of takes much CPU time.  However, you need to look at a tool that deal directly with IP traffic.  Searching for `network monitor linux` should yield some results.

Comment: I am testing 11.3MBps (90Mbps) IPv6 Frag traffic on ubunut. The packet format of this test drive Cisco router CPU utilization up to 99% less than 5 seconds but I can not find out how Ubuntu 11.4 react to this traffic in respect of the CPU utilization exactly. I have used "sar" as well as "top" but I dont know what process ID (or let say process name) is responsible for it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's an excellent CLI program called nethogs that will show you network utilization by process.

Install with `apt-get install nethogs`

Man page: http://linux.die.net/man/8/nethogs

Comment: Thank u. I have installed it and tested it. My network is full IPv6 without any IPv4. In my case nethogs does not even run. So I enabled IPv4 and I get some output from nethogs but next to the abrupt IPv6 traffic as PID shows "?".

Answer (score 0):

1. Perform a packet capture. (`tcpdump`)
2. Examine the packet capture and check what the destination port is.
3. Check which application is listening to that port. (`netstat`)

If no application is listening on that port, then the traffic is either malicious (Denial of Service, etc.) or not intended to be arriving at your system. Either way, you'll likely have to speak with your ISP to get it blocked.

Comment: Thank you. I am running DoS myself with IPv6 fragmentation on Ubuntu 11.4. I need to know how much impact the traffic has on the CPU but I can not find out what process ID is responsible for this traffic.

Comment: I tested tcpdump but still I do not get any PID or CPU usage of the Abrupt fragmented ICMPv6 traffic to determine CPU usage even in -vv mode. The kernel mostly drop the packets (about 80%) but I need to determine how much CPU was used to deal even with the dropping process. 
I am doing research for my thesis so I would really appreciate any help. Thank u.